# The type or namespace name 'Ad' could not be found

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xna

http://geekswithblogs.net/cwilliams/archive/2011/03/20/144452.aspx

I tried this tutorial but I always get the following three error messages:

> The type or namespace name 'Ad' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'AdManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The name 'RotationMode' does not exist in the current context

What is wrong? I already added "using Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.Xna;", but I always get these error messages.

How can I use pubcenter ads in my XNA Windows Phone game?

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private const string AppID = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private const string AdUnitID = "xxxxx";
    AdManager adManager;
    Ad bannerAd;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(333333);
        InactiveSleepTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        adManager = new AdManager(this, AppID);
        adManager.TestMode = false;  
        Components.Add(adManager);
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        bannerAd = adManager.CreateAd(AdUnitID, new Rectangle(0, 20, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds.Width, 120), RotationMode.Manual, false);
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.Xna dll to the reference in your project? Also, after the dll, did you import the dll in your class file?

Comment: Yes, I added the reference and "using Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.Xna;" to my class.